# modify lines containing specific words/characters and not containing others

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I'm stuck in finding a way to modify multiple lines in multiple files that contain specific words/characters but not others. To be more specific, a would like to transform all variable declarations in fortran files from `real` to `real(kind=r8)`. For example the lines below:

- `var= (var1*REAL(j)-var2*REAL(j)*var3)`
- `REAL :: pwr10`
- `INTRINSIC REAL`
- `REAL(kind=r16) :: qr(n), qaorg, qx`
- `REAL, DIMENSION(-1:nx, -1:ny) :: arg1`
- `REAL(kind=r8) :: y3`

should become:

- `var= (var1*REAL(j)-var2*REAL(j)*var3)`
- `REAL(kind=r8) :: pwr10`
- `INTRINSIC REAL`
- `REAL(kind=r16) :: qr(n), qaorg, qx`
- `REAL(kind=r8), DIMENSION(-1:nx, -1:ny) :: arg1`
- `REAL(kind=r8) :: y3`

I know how to select the specific lines using grep but not using sed to modify them. can someone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/REAL\([^(].*::\)/REAL(kind=r8)\1/' file
var= (var1*REAL(j)-var2*REAL(j)*var3)
REAL(kind=r8) :: pwr10
INTRINSIC REAL
REAL(kind=r16) :: qr(n), qaorg, qx
REAL(kind=r8), DIMENSION(-1:nx, -1:ny) :: arg1
REAL(kind=r8) :: y3
```

The `sed` expression

```
s/REAL\([^(].*::\)/REAL(kind=r8)\1/
```

will substitute all `REAL` with `REAL(kind=r8)` provided that

1. The string `REAL` is not immediately followed by a `(`.
2. There is a `::` somewhere later on the same line.

The way I've written it, the `REAL` string may otherwise occur anywhere on the line.  Use `^REAL` in place of the first `REAL` in the expression if the word has occur first on the line (with no spaces or anything between the beginning of the line and the word).

Answer (score 0):

```
perl  -pe '/\h::\h/ && /^\h*REAL(?!\()\K/ and s//(kind=r8)/' input.txt
```

to be read as:

- when each line has a whitespace delimited "::" substring.
- the keyword "REAL" begins at beginning of line optionally preceded by whitespace and does not see an opening bracket to it's right.
- when both the above conditions are met, we perform the substitution.
- the s//(kind=r8)/ command means use the regex from the previous successful match and replace that with whatever's in  the RHS.

**Output**

```
var= (var1*REAL(j)-var2*REAL(j)*var3)
REAL(kind=r8) :: pwr10
INTRINSIC REAL
REAL(kind=r16) :: qr(n), qaorg, qx
REAL(kind=r8), DIMENSION(-1:nx, -1:ny) :: arg1
REAL(kind=r8) :: y3
```